# Can Kazuki borrow or have other kings power?

Tags: magika-no-kenshi

Kazuki can have or borrow other summoner powers by having relationship. So, by doing having relationship with other kings can he have or borrow their powers ?

Comment: when i googled the previous tag i got Magika no Kenshi to Shoukan Vasreus but that was still to big. i think Magika no Kenshi is short enough and easier to read that the previous tag

Comment: This question is answered in the later novels.